# Ruby on Rails sqlite3-ruby gem interfering with heroku push

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I know this question has been answered a million times on SO, but I can't seem to find the right combination of things to fix my dilemma.

This is the error I'm getting:

> An error occurred while installing sqlite-ruby (1.2.5), and Bundler cannot continue.
> Make sure that 'gem install sqlite3-ruby -v '1.2.5'' succeeds before bundling.
>
> Failed to install gems via bundler.
>
> Detected sqlite gem that is not supported on Heroku

I already have Postgres installed on my laptop, and my Gemfile is as follows:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.0.3'
gem 'sqlite3-ruby', '1.2.5'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

Anyone have insight on what I'm doing wrong? I already made sure that my changes are committed via "bundle install" and "bundle".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove the line

```
gem 'sqlite3-ruby', '1.2.5'
```

because you already have the gem `sqlite` in development and test environments, run `bundle install`, and you should be good to go!

Comment: Awesome! Just may want to note that I also had to push my changes to normal git before bundle install in order for your solution to work. Thanks a ton!